# Crystal Reports: including a subreport into a grouping section?

Tags: crystal-reports, grouping, subreport

I have a report which lists out a company detail. There are two sections to the company detail.  The first portion lists out environmental data and the second is actually a subreport which lists out Cash flow details for every single year of the company.

I have multiple companies i need to do this for--so i grouped the report by Company.  This works like a dream except for when it comes to the subreport.  I'm having real issues trying to get it so that every single company has a different subreport of cash flow.  Anybody know how to include a subreport into a group so that every company i have has its own data for the cash flow data?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The subreport has to take a parameter that identifies a company, which the main report will provide.  Then you link the value to the parameter via the subreport properties available on the main report page.

Comment: this does not work.  the param only keeps the subreport together but does not display an individual subreport on each page.  what i mean is that instead of each company displaying an individual subreport of cashflow, it is all clumped together.

Comment: The subreport has to be within the DETAILS section, so as the company id changes, the subreport is re-run based on the company id.  The setup does in fact work, it's how you've got your report laid out that is the issue.

Comment: i have it currently in the DETAILS section and it shows up as so:

CompanyA
data
data 
data
CompanyB
data
data
data

Comment: Do you get the subreport duplicated for each company, including all every companys' data?

Comment: yes i'm afraid that was the issue i was trying to explain before (i apologize if i was unclear).  I just want it so that if i have company a's data showing, i only get company a's subreport for its cashflow

Comment: If I understand correctly then, the subreport is not getting the company id, and in this situation it defaults to selecting all companies.

Comment: The subreport should be in the group header or footer, otherwise it'll repeat once for every row of the relevant company.

Comment: @CodeByMoonlight: Assuming there is a group defined.  Placement is minor at the moment - The bigger issue is that the parameter isn't getting to the subreport.

Comment: Rexem -- thank you for trying to help :)  i really appreciate it.  If i do find out the answer, i will post it up here!

Answer (score 4):

You have to link the subreport to the main report: right-click on the subreport and choose "Edit subreport links". Here you can select the fields to use to link the main report and the subreport.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to link the subreport to the main report: right-click on the subreport and choose "Edit subreport links". Here you can select the fields to use to link the main report and the subreport.
2. Edit Subreport and in Menu, Click Report -> Select Expert and click show formula button. By default it shows Record Selection radio button.
3. You copy that formula and choose Group Selection and paste and give ok.
4. It will work :-)